# Spring Data JPA1.5.x Compatiblity

Tags: spring-data-jpa

After updating library versions in my Gradle build file, I run into the following error which I believe to be a compatibility issue. I lose the previous gradle build file and can't trace back my old version numbers. I am wondering whether someone know the right versions of other Spring project for Spring Data 1.5.x. Thanks.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.postProcess(Lorg/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactory;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)V
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:166)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
```